# script on this page is cause to run slowly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

> ```
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $("#tree").treeview({
>             collapsed: true,
>             animated: "fast",
>             control: "#tree",
>             persist: "location",
>             prerendered: false
>         });
> ```
>
> });

using "jquery.treeview.js" my tree has many nodes more than 200 nodes.

it works but in internet explorer it gives me script alert "this page is causing to run slowly" and it has yes or no button to stop it or not how I can solve it ?

Comment: Have you upgraded to the latest version of jQuery? It seems there is a ticket for that http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is little to derive the exact problem. But it looks like that your script has gone into a infinite looping and that why its showing up this error.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the "prerendered" attribute to TRUE?

I read this in the documentation:

> prerendered   Boolean Default: false
>
> Set to skip rendering of classes and
>   hitarea divs, assuming that is done by
>   the serverside. Makes the tree more
>   obtrusive, but speeds up render times
>   for large trees signicifcantly.